# One-hot encoding of decimals with a fixed precision in python/numpy

Tags: python, numpy, encoding, encode

In Python, I would like to achieve a *one-hot* encoding of decimal numbers with precision until `10^{-3}`. Given that my input fractions are, e.g., `interval = [0.433,0.223,0.111]`, it would produce a stack of one-hot vectors for each number in interval. So for the first float number `0.433` we should get `4 ---> 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0` , `3 ---> 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0`, `3 ---> 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0` and then concatenate the three obtaining a 30 dimensional one-hot array.

Also, I'm wondering about this: even if the input numbers are, let's say, `[0.4,0.2,0.1]`, is there a way to apply the same technique as before? Like considering mathematically equivalent numbers `[0.400,0.200,0.100]`?

EDIT:

This is my proposed attempt. I'm not sure this is the best way to accomplish the result, adn additionally this not solves the case where we are given for example `[0.4, 0.2]` but we want to interpret it as `[0.400, 0.200]` .

```
def encode_digits(floats: list):
            
    decimals = []
    
    for f in floats:
        
        decimals.append(str(f).split('0.',1)[1])
        
    one_hot = []
        
    for i in range(2):
        
        for j in range(3):
            
            temp =np.zeros(10)
            
            temp[int(decimals[i][j])] += 1
            
            one_hot.append(temp)
            
    return np.array(one_hot).reshape(-1)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far based on your own research, and what went wrong with your attempts?

Comment: I'm posting in few minutes my attempt

Comment: @G.Anderson I've posted my (partial) solution.

Comment: Maybe you could try binning and then encoding.

Comment: What do you mean by ‘binning’ ?

Comment: This https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_binning and this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discretization_of_continuous_features could be helpful. I think in pandas there is a cut to do the same (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html#pandas-cut)

Comment: Thanks but I’m thinking I could simply add a try/catch block when I try to run temp[int(decimals..] and if I go out of index then I just sum 1 to temp[0]

Comment: Multiply by 1000 and convert to integer dtype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comment you can multiply by 1000 and convert to integer. Thereafter you can extract each individual digit from the numbers `i` and finally apply standard one-hot encoding:

```
i = (np.array(interval) * 1000).astype(int)
digits = i // 10 ** np.arange(len(i))[::-1, None] % 10
np.eye(10, dtype=int)[digits.T]
```

output:

```
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]])
```

If you prefer to concatenate it into a 30 dimensional array you could do:

```
np.eye(10, dtype=int)[digits.T].reshape(3, 3 * 10)
```

output:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Hi, I was noticing that if I add one more element in interval, like [0.433, 0.233, 0.111, 0.444] this approach is not working anymore.. but i cannot find out why

Comment: @JamesArten I am not sure what the expected results are in that case. But try replacing `np.arange(len(i))` with `np.arange(3)`.