# Convert a vector into a numpy array; discritize them into bins

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, bin

I have a vector, say `v=[0.001, 0.13, 0.2, ..., .9]` with length `365`. All values between `0` and `1`. I want to turn it into a 2D numpy array of size `365-by-100`, i.e. create bins of size 0.01 and see to which bin a given element of `v` belongs to on a given `day` in 1-365.

Let me call the 2D array `M`. I want to have `1` in `M[1, 0]` because `v[0]` on first day belongs to the first bin.

It seems the following gives the location/indicies `(i,j)`'s in `M` that must turn into ```1````.

`matrix_indecies = pd.cut(x=v, bins=np.arange(0, 1, 0.01), labels=False).to_frame().reset_index().to_numpy()`

But I do not know how to convert proper `M[i,j]`'s into 1 without a for-lopp.

Comment: Would rounding each element to the nearest 1/100th work?

Comment: Sure, rounding each element to the nearest 1/100th work

Comment: IIUC: `np.searchsorted(np.linspace(0.01, 1, 100), v)` returns the binned data, `(np.searchsorted(np.linspace(0.01, 1, 100), v)[:,None] == np.arange(100)).astype(np.int32)` the matrix. The bins `array` contains the same information as the one-hot encoded matrix.

Comment: Similar question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71710837/one-hot-encoding-of-decimals-with-a-fixed-precision-in-python-numpy/71716155

Comment: @Kevin - Maybe even a duplicate. But it's difficult to see the similarity if you don't already know the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you don't want to use a for loop in this situation. Seems like a simple solution.

However, here is a version not using a for loop. I'm not sure if a for loop would be faster or slower.

```py
ones_indices = np.floor(v * n_bins)
M = np.zeros((len(v), n_bins), np.bool)
M[np.arange(len(v)), ones_indices] = 1
```

If this is part of a performance critical part of your code you might want to preallocate the M array and the arange array used for indexing.

OR, rewrite the function in `numba` if this functionality really is the bottleneck in your code.

Best of luck!

Comment: "I don't understand why you don't want to use a for loop in this situation." Because there is not only one vector like this. There are a lot of them!

The whole idea behind this is ridiculous. I am stuck with who I am stuck with! so.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making a large matrix where 99% of the matrix is holding 0's you may find it useful to simply round to the nearest 1/100th, ie, round to 2 digits:

```py
np.round(arr, 2)
```

Comment: but this does not give me a 2D array. I want a matrix. as I said, I need to convert it to a 2D array. with 0s and 1s, so that it looks like gray scale image!